# Impossible to deploy a React 16 app to Firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I was already working with Firebase functions so I already had a Firebase project initialized and everything deployed successfully. I created a React app in the Firebase project directory with create-react-app.

But now that I'm trying to deploy the whole thing to Firebase Hosting by running firebase deploy, I have these errors:

```
$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'approof-references-debug'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions
> tslint -p tslint.json


WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[12, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[13, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[14, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[15, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[17, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[18, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[19, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[20, 1]: import with explicit side-effect
WARNING: /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions/src/index.ts[21, 1]: import with explicit side-effect

Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run build

> functions@ build /Users/sarbogast/dev/Derbigum/backend/functions
> tsc

node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts(60,95): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts(60,96): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts(60,116): error TS1005: ';' expected.
../node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(33,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
../node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(33,75): error TS1005: ';' expected.
...
```

And I did not include all the errors but they all look the same.
Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase cli will probably check for lint warnings before deploy if you have that specified in your package.json.

```
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --max-warnings=0 .",
```

Comment: In functions/package.json, I have the following scripts line: "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json"
And in the root package.json, I don't have any lint line like that, just "eslintConfig": { "extends": "react-app"},

Comment: Does it work if you remove the "lint" script? (You should fix the warnings, tho. They warn you for a reason)

Comment: Yes, but why do I have warning in the functions modules for dependencies in the parent module? Plus, all of these warnings are in libraries like React and prop-types. It's not like I can fix those errors myself.

Comment: Plus, if I remove the lint script altogether, as well as the predeploy command running lint from firebase.json, I still get the same error. So it doesn't seem like it's a linting problem: even tsc complains about these libraries. I should mention that my firebase functions are written in Typescript.

Comment: Yes it does. I guess I'm gonna have to deploy functions and hosting separately then